# Destructuring an Option<Box<_>> inside a match statement in Rust

Tags: rust, dereference, destructuring

I have a big object that I need boxed in another object but I don't necessarily need it all the time. So I want to use an if statement to get the optional boxed TempStructure but i'm not exactly sure how I can destructure and dereference at the same time.

Example:

```rust
pub struct TempStructure {
    lots_of_data: [u64; 64],
}
pub struct Structure {
    pending_removal: Option<Box<(TempStructure, bool)>>,
}
impl Structure {
    pub fn do_somthing(&mut self) {
        // How do I destructure the Option and dereference the Box to get TempStructure?
        if let Some((temp_structure, some_boolean)) = self.pending_removal.take() { 
            // Do something with temp_structure and some_boolean
        }
    }
}
```

When I do this ^^^ I get an `` expected struct `std::boxed::Box`, found tuple `` error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dereference the box after matching:

```rust
if let Some(inner) = self.pending_removal.take() {
    let (temp_structure, some_boolean) = *inner;
    // Do something with temp_structure and some_boolean
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a86e2e8e5404856fcb40dd437ff217a)

If you think this is a bit clunky, you're right. On nightly you can use the unstable `box_patterns` feature to enable a better syntax for this (although [this might never be stabilized](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/29641)):

```rust
if let Some(box (temp_structure, some_boolean)) = self.pending_removal.take() {
    // Do something with temp_structure and some_boolean
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c660bffdc36a267f04c84d01a9cd3694)

Comment: I knew about the `box` syntax, but I didn't know it was used for this purpose. Thanks for showing that!

Comment: @Zyansheep, you cannot move out of the `&mut self` iirc.

Answer (score 7):

You can fix this with adding a `.as_deref()` after the `take()`:

```
pub struct TempStructure {
    lots_of_data: [u64; 64],
}
pub struct Structure {
    pending_removal: Option<Box<(TempStructure, bool)>>,
}
impl Structure {
    pub fn do_somthing(&mut self) {
        // How do I destructure the Option and dereference the Box to get TempStructure?
        if let Some((temp_structure, some_boolean)) = self.pending_removal.take().as_deref() { 
            // Do something with temp_structure and some_boolean
        }
    }
}
```

`Box<T>` dereferences to `&T`, `as_deref()` dereferences the value of the `Option`, therefore it gives you a `&T` out of your `Option<Box<T>>`.

Edit: another option is to dereference the Box to move the value out of it:

```
        if let Some((temp_structure, some_boolean)) = self.pending_removal.take().map(|boxed| *boxed) { 
            // assignments just for demonstration purposes that we now get
            // owned values rather than references.
            let _: TempStructure = temp_structure;
            let _: bool = some_boolean;
        }
```

Comment: I think I'm looking to move the tuple out of the box, not just get a reference to a temporary object. Is there any way I can do that with the `.as_deref()` function?

Comment: You can move out of the box by dereferencing:

```Rust
        if let Some((temp_structure, some_boolean)) = self.pending_removal.take().map(|boxed| *boxed) { 
            let _: TempStructure = temp_structure;
            let _: bool = some_boolean;
            // Do something with temp_structure and some_boolean
        }
```

Comment: That would be a good alternative to add to the answer.

Comment: I edited the answer, missing a bit of experience in writing comments on SO, any clue how to fix the code block in the comment above?

Comment: I don't think comments are supposed to have multiline code blocks.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39260/how-do-i-post-code-in-comments

Comment: I don't quite understand the last snippet. Why do you move from `temp_structure` and `some_boolean` to `_` (which discards them) and then have a comment that says "Do something with temp_structure and some_boolean"? Does that actually work? Or is the comment meant to be _before_ the `let` assignments?

Comment: The assignments are just supposed to show that the type of `temp_structure` is now `TempStructure` and `some_boolean` is `bool` and not references as it's the case with `as_deref()`.

I'll edit my answer and remove the comment, I didn't even realize it was there :)